# How can I get the number of register on my grid that using table and not repeater using protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a grid, with 5 elements on it. And I have a pagiation to travel. I need to get the total of item in my grid, but it's uses object. How can I do it?

I don't understand the HTML, is it using object? 
I don't a clue how to do it.

** Partial HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><tr class="ui-state-default">
                            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Tipo de Norma</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Número</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Ano</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Descrição</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Status</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Data de Publicação</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title">Ativo</span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th><th ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="kebab-column ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" ng-reflect-initial-classes="kebab-column" draggable="false" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-column-title"></span>
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->
                    </thead>
                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                    <tbody class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
                        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->
                            <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-initial-classes="ui-widget-content">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Lei</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">1800</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">1800</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Teste para ver se norma esta desativada</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Revogado</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">01/08/2016</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Inativo</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="kebab-column" ng-reflect-initial-classes="kebab-column" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">
                                        <p-columntemplateloader ng-reflect-column="[object Object]" ng-reflect-row-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-row-index="0"></p-columntemplateloader>

        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><button class="btn btn-flat btn-no-text btn-kebab-view">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i>
        </button>

        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->


                                    </span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->

                            <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-initial-classes="ui-widget-content">
                                <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Resolução</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">333</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">2011</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">teste</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                </td><td ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="ui-cell-data">Revogado</span>
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
                                    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
```

.
.
.

```
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can not follow.

Comment: do you need to  count the number of records available in the table?

Comment: @SebastianSebald I have a grid, with 5 elements on it. And I have a pagiation to travel.
I need to get the total of item in my grid, but it's uses object. How can I do it?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj Basically yes.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj what do you mean by "uses object"?

Comment: You can simply use xpath or css to get the row count in the table. try the below example.

 ```var count = element.all(by.css("table>tbody>tr")).count()``` or 
```var count = element.all(by.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr")).count()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor is only a helpful wrapper around Selenium, you shouldn't access any JavaScript `Object`s to count something. In order to count the rows of a table use [`element.all(by.css('table td'))`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).

If you have pagination this makes counting a bit more tricky. You can wrap the above call in an [`.each` loop](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each). Inside the loop you go to the next page, wait until its loaded and then count.